# How to disable eslint from package.json on an angular project?

Tags: angular, eslint, package.json

I have this in my package.json of an angular project, how can I disable it?

`

```
"eslint": "^6.8.0",
```

`

I did try to delete it with no success, so I just want to disable it for now

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall the package from the project using npm

```
npm uninstall eslint
```

Remove any .eslint files from the project, make sure to double check and delete if eslint still appears in the package.json

Comment: Thanks a lot! And is there a way to disable it?

Comment: Normally I just remove the configuration files from the project.  I am not aware of a specific way to get that done.